# Creating a frame class in order to make many InternalFrames

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, jbutton

**BACKGROUND**

I'm creating a hostel booking software as a project to learn java. I have my main frame which holds buttons that open each room by setting the containing frame to visible. I have an add room button that asks me how many beds the room as and stores this as an int.

**QUESTION**

Would it be possible to have a room class that would allow me to create new rooms by pressing the button? That means creating an InternalFrame, JPanel and JButtons, adding the buttons to a grid based off the bed number int.

I feel like the idea is there but the implementation is proving tricky since im new to java. Any ideas are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: *"Would it be possible to have a room class that would allow me to create new rooms by pressing the button?"*  Yes.  What have you tried?

Comment: Currently most of my code is in one file, nested in the main frame class.. As im learning more about java Ive started moving things into their own files slowly.. I was using ArrayList and trying to initialise my frames all internally until I thought about classes

Comment: And im using internal frames for the windows sorry

Answer (score 0):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Internal Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html).

The demo in the tutorial shows how to dynamically create internal frames when clicking in a menu item. The concept is the same for buttons. You just add the `ActionListener` to the button.

Of course you will need to change the code to create your own custom panel. You will also probably want to use a `JOptionPane` to prompt the user for the number of rooms. Again the tutorial has a section on `How to Use Dialogs` for an example of using a `JOptionPane`.